# How to remove an input if the maximum number is met or Exceeded? PHP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to remove this button after the number exceeded to the maximum number so for example

So I have a prev and next button. So if I next it and it incrementally counts till the value is met, then the button should be removed.

I have this ** 1 / 5 **

So if the 1 is incremented to 5 then the button should be removed.

Here is HTML

```
// So in the UI this is 1 / 5
<h4><?php echo  $num++; ?>.)  <?php echo $question->question ?></h4> 

<div class="card-body">
        <?php foreach($this->question_model->findAnswersByQuestion($question->id) as $answer){ ?>

                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter Answer" name="question_<?php echo $question->id; ?>"/>
                </div>

        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

So here are my buttons which are **prev** and **next** - So NEXT should be remove at the end of the number when it counts

```
<span class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-style" id="btn-prev" style="display:none;" type="submit">Prev</span>
        <?php if($num_count > 3): ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <span class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-style" id="btn-next" style="display:none; float:right;" type="submit">Next</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(function() {

  $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#btn-next").show();
    $("#btn-prev").show();
    $("#btn-submit").show();
    var next_tab = $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a');
    if (next_tab.length > 0) {
      next_tab.trigger('click');
    } else {
      $('.nav-tabs li:eq(0) a').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});

$(".btn-style").click(function() {
  var target = $(".nav-tabs li.active");
  var sibbling;
  if ($(this).text() === "Next") {
    sibbling = target.next();
  } else {
    sibbling = target.prev();
  }
  if (sibbling.is("li")) {
    sibbling.children("a").tab("show");
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need JS at all for this task. The PHP-part of your code knows what question you are at, right? If it already knows that, there is no need for JS to figure out, if it should show or hide the buttons... Try with checking for the first and last question in the PHP-part and show the buttons based on that evaluation

Comment: @Argee - but my questions are in loop, can you provide a pseudo code please? thanks

Comment: I tried it below :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be the pseudo code, you asked for. That's the way I would approach the problem, you might have to adjust some things so it works with your datastructure ;)

```
$questions = [...];
foreach($questions as $questionIndex => $question) {
    // render question
    // render answers

    // add buttons conditionally like so:
    if($questionIndex === 0) {
        // only render next button
    } elseif ($questionIndex === count($questions) - 1) {
        // only render previous button
    } else {
        // render both buttons
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

without knowing your code it's really hard to tell... maybe this here helps you more: it's a "standalone example" of what I have described...

```
<?php
$questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3"];

$answers = [["q1answer1", "q1answer2", "q1answer3"], ["q2answer1", "q2answer2", "q2answer3"], ["q3answer1", "q3answer2", "q3answer3"]];

foreach($questions as $questionIndex => $question) {
    // render question
    echo $question."\n";
    // render answers
    foreach($answers[$questionIndex] as $answer) {
        echo $answer."\n";
    }

    // add buttons conditionally like so:
    if($questionIndex === 0) {
        // only render next button
        showButton("next");
    } elseif ($questionIndex === count($questions) - 1) {
        // only render previous button
        showButton("prev");
    } else {
        // render both buttons
        showButton("prev");
        showButton("next");
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
}

function showButton($buttonName) {
    echo "\nbutton ".$buttonName;
}
```

Comment: I understand it, but the "next" button is not showing at the beginning sir, only the "prev" button is showing. thanks

Comment: maybe the `$questionIndex` is different in your code? maybe the first question does not have `0` as its first index?